# PreferenceFragment not shown when using ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity, material-design

I have a `PreferenceFragment` and it can be shown inside an `Activity`. However, when I switch the `Activity` to an `ActionBarActivity`, the fragment is not shown. (I can only see an action bar and a blank white screen below.) The theme I am using is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, therefore I need to use `ActionBarActivity` in order to display the `ActionBar`.

Here is my original code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity { // later changed to extend ActionBarActivity    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Backward compatibility is not my main concern (my `minSdkVersion` is 16). I use `ActionBarActivity` because this is the way I can show an `ActionBar` with the newer material theme. Can you suggest what I can do? And why does it cause problems when `PreferenceFragment` and the hosting `ActionBarActivity` are in different libraries?

Comment: In Android 5.0 Lollipop, you should use widget 'ToolBar' for replacing ActionBar. And use 'getSupportFragmentManager()' replacing 'getFragmentManager()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm extending `ActionBarActivity` and my `PreferenceFragment` works.

I think you need to call `setContentView()` on your Activity, to have an activity layout in which the fragment will be loaded.

activity_preference_layout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="your.package.SettingsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preference_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then your Activity should be something like:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference_layout);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.preference_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Note that I've replaced `android.R.id.content` with `R.id.preference_container`, which is the frame defined in the layout above.

Comment: But why does `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();` work when I am only extending `Activity`?

Comment: I don't know what `android.R.id.content` is, but I think that might be causing your issue with `ActionBarActivity`.